# NSString remove line breaks (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I'm loading data from XML to my NSString, but data is formated like this:

```
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
    consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Sed a velit ut nulla tincidunt finibus sit amet sed felis. 
    Fusce quis quam sapien.
```

It has line breaks, how can I romeve that so the text looks like this(all in one line):

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a velit ut nulla tincidunt finibus sit amet sed felis. Fusce quis quam sapien. Cras diam metus, viverra in urna sed, efficitur varius sem. Pellentesque accumsan, lectus at rutrum pulvinar,
```

Comment: It's an NSString. Have you looked at the NSString documentation to see if there's a method that might do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *newString = [[oldString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```